# Unable to buy shares of Nexus Select Trust?

Tags: bse-india

I have been reading about REITs in India and decided to take a plunge by investing in [Nexus Select Trust](https://www.google.com/finance/quote/543913:BOM). But whenever I try to place order for its shares I get messages like `Only limit order allowed as the security has limited liquidity` OR `Market orders are blocked for NXST. Try placing a Limit or SL order.`

This [Zerodha article](https://support.zerodha.com/category/trading-and-markets/margin-leverage-and-product-and-order-types/articles/what-does-rms-blocked-for-optstk-mkt-mean) mentions that:

> Market & Stop Loss Market [SL-M] orders are restricted in stock and
> commodity options due to a lack of liquidity...
>
> ...A lack of liquidity means that the bid and ask spread in the scrip
> is very high and can have an immediate adverse effect on your P&L.

I am not investing a huge sum here so a bit confused. I have ever only invested in Nifty 100 companies so I never got messages like these.

My question is, if the shares are illiquid, should I be investing in the company at all?

Comment: Probably not, unless you have reason to believe that will change.